# Why is my ARIMA forecast so poor?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, arima

I have a time series going from 2013 until late 2016. I am using the auto.arima function in R to forecast the next 12 months. I get the following where the black line are my observations and the blue line is my prediction.

```
fcast <- forecast(auto.arima(a.ts))
plot(forecast(fcast, h = 12))
```

[image: arima forecast]

However when I use this custom arima function I get a much better result

```
fit <- arima(a.ts,seasonal=list(order=c(0,1,0),period=12))
plot(forecast(fcast, h = 12))
```

[image: custom arima]

Why is the auto.arima function not producing a result that doesn't seem anywhere near as good. I know they are using different parameters but I would have thought that auto.arima would have found the best parameters and forecasted using those?

Comment: When things don't meet your expectations then you  have to reduce your expectations or use other "things" .

Comment: Did you specify the frequency of the time series for `auto.arima`?

Comment: There's not really enough information even for people familiar with `auto.arima` to do more than guess what the issue is here: if it's not merely that the seasonal `period` argument needs to be supplied, please edit the question to give more detail & it can of course be re-opened. [Auto.arima with daily data: how to capture seasonality/periodicity?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/14742/17230) may also be helpful.